# how to get sorted index of min values of 2d array

Tags: javascript

having 2d number array like;

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 5, 9],
  [2, 7, 8],
  [3, 0, 6],
];
```

what is the simplest way to get sorted array of array indexes where sort critera is values of original 2d array?

result should be:

```
  `[2,1]`, // (value=0)
  `[0,0]`, // (value=1)
  `[2,0]`, // (value=2)
  `[0,1]`, // (value=3)
  ...
```

btw, actual values are floats not that it matters.
but complexity does matter as loop runs on each frame.

Comment: *" that's what this forum is for"* . No it is not. It is neither a help desk or a forum. It is expected you show what you have tried. What part of the above comment is unclear? You certainly are asking for others to write code for you as you have shown none of your own

Comment: Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the indices first and sort them by the value of the matrix.

```js
const
    array = [[1, 5, 9], [2, 7, 8], [3, 0, 6]],
    result = array
        .flatMap((a, i) => a.map((_, j) => [i, j]))
        .sort((a, b) => array[a[0]][a[1]] - array[b[0]][b[1]]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
const arr = [
  [1, 5, 9],
  [2, 7, 8],
  [3, 0, 6],
];

const map = []

arr.forEach((row, rowIndex) => row.forEach((col, colIndex) => {
  map.push({ c: colIndex, r: rowIndex, value: col });
}))

console.log(map)
const sorted = map.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.value === b.value) return 0;
  return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
})

console.log(sorted)
console.log(sorted.map(v => [v.r, v.c]))
```

it's working version, not optimalized

EDIT:
little optimalization with execution time measure:

```
const arr = [
  [1, 5, 9],
  [2, 7, 8],
  [3, 0, 6],
];

const sortFn = (a, b) => a.value === b.value ? 0 : a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;

let count = 3;
function process(arr) {
  const map = []
  arr.forEach((row, rowIndex) => row.forEach((col, colIndex) => {
    map.push({ row: rowIndex, col: colIndex, value: col });
  }))
  return map.sort(sortFn).map(v => [v.row, v.col]);
}

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.time("process");
  console.log(process(arr))
  console.timeEnd("process");
  if(--count === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 100)
```

Output:

```
[
  [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2 ]
]
process: 3.822ms
[
  [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2 ]
]
process: 1.661ms
[
  [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2 ]
]
process: 1.665ms
```

EDIT 2:
(inspired by another answer with `flatMap`)

```
const arr = [
  [1, 5, 9],
  [2, 7, 8],
  [3, 0, 6],
];

const sortFn = (a, b) => a.value === b.value ? 0 : a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
arr.flatMap((_row, row) => _row.map((value, col) => { return { row, col, value } })).sort(sortFn).map(v => [v.row, v.col]);

let count = 3;
const process = (arr) => arr.flatMap((_row, row) => _row.map((value, col) => { return { row, col, value } })).sort(sortFn).map(v => [v.row, v.col]);

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.time("process");
  console.log(process(arr))
  console.timeEnd("process");
  if(--count === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 100)
```

Result:

```
[
  [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2 ]
]
process: 10.979ms
[
  [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2 ]
]
process: 1.346ms
[
  [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2 ]
]
process: 2.043ms
```

Comment: works like a charm, but for optimization purposes best to avoid creating interim object and push values as array instead.

Comment: yeah, I edit answer and add version with `flatMap` but it's slower.

Comment: thats surprising but good to know!

Comment: sorry, my computer updating when I measuring `flatMap` version, but when I measure on idle it's very similar results (testing on MacMini M1 and node v16.11.1)